# Does (Hibernate/JPA) EntityManager when used with c3p0, use multiple connections within the same transaction?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, c3p0

When using Hibernate/JPA with c3p0, if multiple POs are being saved i.e. if records are being inserted into several tables, in the same database, within one (EntityManager) transaction, will hibernate use multiple connections to do this or simply use any one connection (from the connection pool)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction (such as that started by `begin()` and commited by `commit()` of `javax.persistence.EntityTransaction`) is associated with the same connection from resource pool.

For example, in `JdbcTransaction`, `begin()` will store a connection retrieved from the pool into a private variable called `managedConnection`.  When you call `commit()`, it will invoke `commit` from this `managedConnection`. If this variable already associated with a connection when you called `begin()`, it will raise a `TransactionException`.